# c# application doesn't work properly in some pc

Tags: c#, image, listview, backgroundworker

I have developed an application that loaded many images in a listview using ImageList in c# .net framework 4. The images are also compressed. When many many images are loaded and compressed then it takes a long time. So I call the method in backgroundworker. In the backgroundworker I had to add images to ImageList and add ImageList to ListView. So I have used safeinvoke() method listView1.SafeInvoke(d=>d.Items.Add(item)).
Everything works fine. Images are displayed one by one in the listview.
But the release of the application doesn’t work properly in some pc and properly works in some other pc. Doesn’t work properly means, If 100 images are browsed using OpenFileDialog to load then some images are loaded and added to listview and then the loading is automatically stopped without adding all images to the listview and no exception shows.

I have spent many times to solve this problem but couldn’t figure out the problem. . Where is the problem? Can anybody help me?

```
 private void bgwLoading_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
         {

            ArrayList a = (ArrayList)e.Argument;

            string[] fileNames = (string[])a[0];

            this.loadMultiImages(fileNames);

        }

 private void loadMultiImages(string[] fileNames)        
  {
             int i = 1;
             int totalFiles = fileNames.Count();

                foreach (string flName in fileNames)
                {
                  if (!flName.Contains("Thumbs.db"))
                    {
                        Bitmap newBtmap = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(flName);

                        FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(flName);
                        long l = fi.Length;

                        if (l > compressSize)
                        {
                                newBtmap = resizeImage(newBtmap, 1024,768) ;
                                newBtmap = saveJpeg(IMAGE_PATH + (SCANNING_NUMBER +  
                                ) + ".jpg", newBtmap, IMAGE_QUALITY);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            File.Copy(flName, TEMP_IMAGE_PATH + (SCANNING_NUMBER + 1) + ".jpg");

                        }



                        if (!bgwLoading.CancellationPending)
                        {
                            CommonInformation.SCANNING_NUMBER++;
                            this.SafeInvoke(d => d.addItemToLvImageContainer(newBtmap));
                            bgwLoading.ReportProgress((int)Math.Round((double)i / (double) 
                            (totalFiles) * 100));

                            i++;
                           }                        
                   }
                }
             }

        }

        public void addItemToLvImageContainer(Bitmap newBtmap)
          {
              imageList.Images.Add(newBtmap);
             ListViewItem item;
             item = new ListViewItem();
             item.ImageIndex = SCANNING_NUMBER - 1;
             item.Text = SCANNING_NUMBER.ToString();
             lvImageContainer.Items.Add(item);
             lvImageContainer.Items[item.ImageIndex].Focused = true;

          }
```

To find out the error I have modified the code as follows:

I have commented the two lines

```
          //newBtmap = resizeImage(newBtmap, 1024, 768);

         // newBtmap = saveJpeg(IMAGE_PATH + scanning_number + ".jpg", newBtmap, Image_Quality );
```

and added try-catch as follows:

```
                   try
                       {
                            Bitmap newBtmap = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(flName);

                              File.Copy(flName, CommonInformation.TEMP_IMAGE_PATH + 
                              (CommonInformation.SCANNING_NUMBER + 1) + ".jpg");


                                 if (!bgwLoading.CancellationPending)
                                  {
                                    this.SafeInvoke(d => d.imageList.Images.Add(newBtmap));


                                    ListViewItem item;
                                    item = new ListViewItem();

                                    CommonInformation.SCANNING_NUMBER++;

                                    item.ImageIndex = CommonInformation.SCANNING_NUMBER - 1;
                                    item.Text = CommonInformation.SCANNING_NUMBER.ToString();
                                    this.SafeInvoke(d => d.lvImageContainer.Items.Add(item));

                                    bgwLoading.ReportProgress((int)Math.Round((double)i / 
                                   (double)(totalFiles) * 100));

                                     this.safeInvoke(d=>d.addItemImageContainer(newBtmap)) 

                               catch (Exception ex)
                               {
                                     MessageBox.Show( ex.Message);

                                 }
```

It shows the error message after loading some images as "OutOfMemoryException"

Most probably the following line creates the exception:

Bitmap newBtmap = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(flName);

But the image files are not corrupted and their file extension is .JPG.

How to get rid of this problem?

Comment: Can you please add some logging to your code to indicate if it fails on a specific image or at a certain iteration? i.e. it's always the same image that fails it? Also, do you have any clue as to a common denominator between the PCs demonstrating the failure? I found that on some occasions Controls running under threads without exception handling cause the application to abort without notice. Doesn't happen often at all, but got to experience it a few times. I solved my issue by adding exception handling on both the (additemtolv...) and the external call before the safeinvoke.

Comment: Try not doing it multithreaded and see if the problem goes away. The symptoms you are describing smell of threading synchronization. Release runs with different timing/optimization than debug and so your code may not run quite the same

Comment: @mr.kav                                                                It's not the same image that fails it? sometimes I can load 30 iamges, sometimes 20 that is after a uncertain period of time exception occurs.

Answer (score 0):

I have no answer, but i have some suggestions:

1. Check .NET framework version on computers with problems
2. Check, if you have permissions for files you trying to read
3. Use "try-catch" when you accessing files

And questions:

1. Is this project written in older version of .NET and migrated/upgraded to .NET 4.0?
2. Are you using any non-built-in assemblies or external dll's for image processing?

Comment: 1. The project is developed .net framework 4 using vs2010. It is not migrated.